SwiftUI (Mac) @Observable memory leak, related to an array, triggers App lifecycle
Using @Observable view model with an array collection, if addressed in init, will trigger a second App lifecycle when mutated.
Breaking it up:
Root:
@main
struct MyApp: App {
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            MainContentView()
        }
    }
}

ViewModel
@Observable
class ContentViewModel {
    var items = [String]()
    
    init() {
        print("Init")
        if items.isEmpty {}
    }

    deinit {
        print("deinit")
    }

    
    func update() {
        items.append("New")
    }
}


View:
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var viewModel: ContentViewModel = .init()
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("Update", action: viewModel.update)
    }
}

When running this, it will print "Init" (expected of course), but clicking "Update" triggers a complete lifecycle.
It will print another "Init". Setting a breakpoint on the (single) WindowGroup will stop there. Meaning (I think) that the whole var body: some Scene is getting triggered.

By simply removing items.isEmpty, the problem goes away.
The memory graph is showing the ContentViewModel twice.
There's no deinit.
Only happens with @Observable (does not happens if using ObservableObject/ObservedObject)


Yes this is a known problem of @Observable. It will only leak at most one object as far as I know. What actually is your question?

That was the question. Wasn't able to find anything about it really. Couldn't tell if it could leak multiple times, so good to know it's only leak this once. Was just filling a bug report to Apple, guess there's no need. (BTW, where is this issue known? I was not able to find anything here)

It is in the docs, you have to init as optional and use .task

Sorry, not seeing it, only some Apple threads on iOS. The Apple page "Migrating from the Observable Object protocol to the Observable macro" mention nothing about memory, init or leak. Downloaded the sample project, there's no init in the view models. They do use final class, but it leaks just the same.

I can delete this post, but the next one getting this issue I think will not find any answers. It's root source is not obvious, I took my project apart until I narrowed it down to the array-@Observable-init. Did all kind of searches, came up empty. @ lorem ipsum, where is the optional init and using .task posted?

Look at the State documentation

You have to use @StateObject the docs are out of date. And ViewModel is not a good name for the model store object.

@malhal You cannot use with @StateObject with @Observable, only @State. Also, ViewModel is a simplified name for this sample, and it is a view model, not model. If I had 'data' kind Models, the view model would be using them.

Not sure why you think you can't? It's just @Observable class Model: ObservableObject nothing special. The reason you shouldn't use ViewModel for a StateObject name is the View structs are the view models already.

The key difference between @StateObject and @State is that the property initialiser of @State is called every time the view's initialiser is called.
So after viewModel is first initialised, you end up creating a temporary instance of ContentViewModel every subsequent time that ContentView.init is called.
Normally, the temporary instance is immediately deinitialised, but it can still affect performance if you are doing something heavy in the @Observable class' initialiser. This is pointed out in the documentation for State.

A State property always instantiates its default value when SwiftUI
instantiates the view. For this reason, avoid side effects and
performance-intensive work when initializing the default value. For
example, if a view updates frequently, allocating a new default object
each time the view initializes can become expensive. Instead, you can
defer the creation of the object using the task(priority:_:)
modifier, which is called only once when the view first appears:
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var library: Library?


    var body: some View {
        LibraryView(library: library)
            .task {
                library = Library()
            }
    }
}


Sometimes, one extra instance is retained because of some quirks in SwiftUI's algorithm of creating a dependency graph. From my experience, I have only seen at most one extra instance per @State.
In your case, the line if items.isEmpty {} access the observation-tracked property items, and this access is registered in the observationRegistrar. This affects SwiftUI's dependency graph one way or another, and the instance is not released.
You can solve this by doing what the documentation recommends - making it optional and initialising it in task or onAppear.
Alternatively, you can use this property wrapper by malhal.
@MainActor
@propertyWrapper struct StateObservable<T>: DynamicProperty where T: Observable & AnyObject {
    @StateObject var storage: Storage
    
    class Storage: ObservableObject {
        @Published var object: T // @Published allows the object to be replaced and body will be called
        init(object: T) {
            self.object = object
        }
    }
    
    var wrappedValue: T {
        get {
            return storage.object
        }
        nonmutating set {
            storage.object = newValue
        }
    }
    
    // this allows $ syntax to be used in the same View where the wrapper is declared.
    var projectedValue: Bindable<T> {
        get {
            Bindable(storage.object)
        }
    }
    
    @inlinable public init(wrappedValue thunk: @autoclosure @escaping () -> T) {
        _storage = StateObject(wrappedValue: Storage(object: thunk()))
    }
}

This property wrapper wraps the property initialiser expression into an @autoclosure, so that it acts similarly to @StateObject.

In my use case, I've reverted to using the ObservableObject/StateObject, otherwise, I'de just write it such that it can handle multiple inits (not performing any expected 'single' events). In my case, the whole lifecycle up to the @main App and WindowGroup is triggered, so even holding @State at the App scope does not retain its value. It's tricky since it would be like getting didFinishLaunching multiple times. Possibly, 'twice' is better than 'multiple' (it's contained), but still. Appreciate the answer and education value!
